# Change background color of the selected line in a textarea

Tags: jquery

I have textarea control in MVC project. Also I have two buttons "UP" and "DOWN". Imagine that in textarea exist 3 lines of text. I want after load page backlight in background first line of textarea. When I press "DOWN" button, the first line will be usual background and second is with background that was first line before.

So my question is: Can I with jQuery script backlight one line in text area? If yes, How can I do it?

From HTML I have only this:

```
<textarea id="XMLView" rows="30" wrap='off' style="width: 95%">
line1
line2
line3
</textarea>
```

In jQuery I have this:

```
$("#XMLView").Hover(function () {
    $("#XMLView").HoverLine.BackGroung-Color="red";
    alert($("#XMLView").HoverLine.Text);
});
```

Comment: Question is a little broad. Could you post what you've tried? Can you post your HTML/DOM structure? What is meant by "backlight"?

Comment: I edited. Please look.

Comment: This feels like an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. But I will post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping in mind that the question seems to be  a prime candidate for [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), here is a solution to this specific scenario, although it's not particularly elegant.

For HTML, you can not render (the vast majority of) markup within a textarea, so to manipulate the CSS it's easiest to use `<div contenteditable="true">` and create items within the div with classes/ids to access the DOM elements by.

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p tabindex="1" class="focusColor focused">line1</p>
    <p tabindex="2" class="focusColor">line2</p>
    <p tabindex="3" class="focusColor">line3</p>
</div>
```

Simple CSS to apply your background color. It's a bit silly but you can use either `.focused` class or `:focus` functionality, I prefer the built in `:focus` because the `.focused` class is a little contrived.

CSS:

```
.focusColor:focus {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

The Javascript was taken largely from another Stackoverflow thread, adding our customization (up/down keys, codes 38/40 respectively) and `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`. Which is a bit finicky and requires more knowledge on what else you want the keydown event to trigger.

JS:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){    
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        if($('.focused').prev('.focusColor').length){
            $('.focused').removeClass('focused').prev('.focusColor').focus().addClass('focused');
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        if($('.focused').next('.focusColor').length){
            $('.focused').removeClass('focused').next('.focusColor').focus().addClass('focused');
        }
    }
});
```